# Getting troubles making status bar hovering the activity

Tags: android, web-applications, statusbar

I have a web site, and I decided to make an Android application for it, but I actually write under win32 on c++, and have never programming under Android. So I decided to make just a Blink render instance, fit it the screen size in my app and load automatically my site. Also I want the status bar hovering on the "activity", searched the internet but can't do this, so please point me, where am I wrong. Stuff should work from Android 4.4 and above. Working in Android Studio

What do I have now:

[image]

What do I want to:

[image]

My code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    />
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://somesite.com");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on onCreate this will make both transparent

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

or try

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Comment: both who? It seems I already have a transparent status bar, but  I need to shift the activity under it

Comment: did you tried it ?? i have edited ans try second one also

Comment: Sorry I have an old hardware, I just can't run Android emulator. Now I'm in library trying to download any portable emulator to test

Comment: No, nothing changed. I put getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS); after getWindow().getDecorView(...

Answer (score 0):

Add progress bar on top of your webview

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/pB1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="2dip">
</ProgressBar>
```

And then you need to set progress status on the progressbar like this:

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
               if(progress < 100 && pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                   pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                   }

               pbar.setProgress(progress);
               if(progress == 100) {
                   pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                  }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Progress? You meant status bar(stuff with time, battery, and another things)? Or it is the same?

Comment: pbar is undefined, also